# Virtual Server to display ASP.NET MVC web application

Tags: asp.net, virtual-server

In a few weeks I have to demonstrate a project I've been working on and at the moment I've just been using the Visual Studio Express 2012 debug with IIS Expess. The project is simply an ASP.NET MVC web application that I access on an android device through WebView.

I was just wondering, is it possible to set up my laptop as a virtual server? At the demonstration I won't have internet that both the laptop and android will be able to connect to.

Is there another way to do it? Possibly by tethering the devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup your Windows 7 laptop as a WIFI hotspot.

right-click the Cmd.exe link and select "Run as Administrator".

Now type the following command:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=MyNet key=MyPassword
```

and press [Enter]. Replace "MyNet" with the name you'd like to use for your custom network, and "MyPassword" with a password that's a little harder to guess.

Still at the command line, type

```
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

and press [Enter] to fire up the virtual adapter.

Now click Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Centre > Change Adapter Settings, right-click your internet connection and select Properties. Click the Sharing tab, check "Allow other network users to connect...", choose your virtual Wi-Fi adaptor - and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was able to do this but when I try and access the debugging website from my android through the webview, it can't access it. Do you know of anything extra that needs to be done? The android was able to connect to the wifi hotspot. I have the correct ip for the webview and I have changed the settings as outlined [on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328090/debugging-an-asp-net-mvc-application-on-an-android-phone)

Comment: I think the error was originally something to do with my laptop. At first your solution was only partly working, but after about 3 days of debugging on my laptop I was finally able to get it to work properly. Thanks :-) The project went well too.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set up your android device as a Wifi hot spot and have your laptop connect to it. There's native functionality in various places depending on the android version, or just go through the Play store searching for "wifi hotspot" and you should be able to go from there.

Make note of the IP your laptop gets and you should be able to connect to it through your android browser of choice on the designated port.