# Run ASP.NET application on server and access from remote computer/phone

Tags: android, asp.net, ip, iis-express

I am trying to debug my visual studio 2012 asp.net project from my phone and have followed all steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328090/debugging-an-asp-net-mvc-application-on-an-android-phone) and [here](http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer).

However none of them work, can't even connect from my other laptop. When I add my public IP or use * IISExpress doesnt even seem to pick up on it (Can't find it in IISExpress->show all applications). But When I used my local IP at least it showed up there and I could connect to it from my own computer, but no other computer/phone.

The cmd commands are successful, I add the extra binding, I open the firewall. Dont know what is wrong.

Which IP (local/public) should I use? what should I type in as URL when I want to test it? I am trying http://IP:port and http://IP:port/Default.aspx.

EDIT: Using [this](https://gilesey.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/allowing-remote-access-to-your-iis-express-service/) solution I got it to work on my laptop, however I still can not get it to work on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the points mentioned in the links you have cited are enough for enabling communication with the phone.  But here is one point to make sure (since you have not mentioned it):  You have to make sure that both the server and the clients (in your case, the machine that runs the visual studio and your phone and the *other* laptop) are on the same wireless network.  To find out the IP that your server/development machine is currently using, you can issue ipconfig command in cmd and look at the Wireless Network Adapter IPV4 address.  For example, if your laptop IP address is 192.168.1.2, you should use http://192.168.1.2:8080/Default.aspx (assuming that your site runs on the port 8080).

Comment: Your answer makes it sound like you need the local IP of the client. That's not correct, you need the local IP of the server.

Comment: I am sorry if I caused confusion.  Your laptop is your server, isn't it?  So I am referring to the local IP of the Server, not the client, which is your phone.

Comment: It sound like they're using three devices. A server (which could be a laptop), and two clients (a laptop and a phone). So you need to make it explicitly clear (edit your answer) to specify which you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You use the local IP if you're on the same network as your server (for example, use WiFi on your phone and join the same network that your server is on).

You use the public IP if the device is outside your network, and you have to configure the firewall to [forward the correct ports](http://portforward.com/help/firewalls.htm) to the local IP. That's NAT traversal. This would be if you're using the phone's cellular data connection, or you're using a WiFi or wired network that's different from the one your server is on.

Your URL should always be of the format `<protocol>://<IP or DNS name>:<port>/<path>`. However, you can omit the IP (and the colon) if you're using HTTP on port 80, or HTTPS on port 443. And you can omit the path if you're accessing the root of the site, and your site has a page correctly configured for the root (either via default document in IIS, or route defaults if you're using routing features).