# Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise - Never loads SLN file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I regularly open projects and they never finish loading. It sits there showing me a populated solution explorer and source files however I cannot click on anything. It constantly shows "We'll automatically report this delay based on your..." every time I click however the UI never responds to me clicking on anything

It will do this for hours and never finish (left it going out of curiosity). If I open the .sln file 2-3x eventually it loads and I have to task kill the previous instances.

It never says not responding or gives me the white/grey screen it just never loads. If I right click close or click the close in the top right it acknowledges the click but never closes. What can I try?

It seems to be more likely to work if I open the project and make sure not to click on anything until it has been open at least 30 seconds. All projects appear to be affected.

edit: No anti virus/malware installed other than windows defender.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the [".vs"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31879242/1364007) folder in the solution directory?

Comment: No but I can try that.

Comment: Questions like this need to document the installed anti-malware product.

Comment: I have no antivirus or anti malware installed other than windows 10 defender.

Comment: Did deleting the .vs folder work?

Comment: Just for reference, do you have any other significant VS plugins installed? Tools like Resharper?

Comment: Yes I have resharper installed. Deleting the vs folder didn't work. Seems to happen roughly about 1 in 5 opens. Because it happens not that often it is hard to disable resharper and test.