# What files from Visual Studio 2017 Project/Solution should be in a SVN ignore?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, projects-and-solutions, svncommit

I'm working on a solution (C#) with 3 projects in it (one library and two applications) and I wonder what is the bare minimum of files you need to commit to be able to pull off a fresh solution and get it to work right away?

Obviously all source files, *.sln, *.csproj are needed and not the obj folder or bin folder (unless I want to keep a working copy of the compiled files).
But do I need to commit the:

```
Properties folder
.vs folder
*.resx
*.config
```

I have Googled it but all I found was a list of the file types, but no explanation of what files where critical to make the solution/project load and compile.

**[EDIT]**
It has been suggested that this is the same question as: [Should I add the Visual Studio 2015 .vs folder to source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878901/should-i-add-the-visual-studio-2015-vs-folder-to-source-control)
The question is not related to *only* the .vs folder, but to all project/solution files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I add the Visual Studio 2015 .vs folder to source control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31878901/should-i-add-the-visual-studio-2015-vs-folder-to-source-control)

Answer (score 0):

Though SVN and Git are different Version Control System, I think the files that should be excluded in the Version Control System should be similar. This file is a ignore file for Git (an .gitignore), but should be work as it should in SVN Version Control Systems.

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

This file is often used in various places like [Github Destktop](https://desktop.github.com/), or the [Github Site](https://github.com/) itself.