# Why is applicationhost.config still being added to source control even thought it's in gitignore

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, gitignore

First of all, I've seen [.vs\config\applicationhost.config in source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363172/vs-config-applicationhost-config-in-source-control).

We are working in a team and Visual Studio changes some path inside `applicationhost.config` file. We need to exclude this. In my `.gitignore` file, I've added:

`/.vs/config/applicationhost.config`

However, in every commit, this is again added to the git. Before VS2015 Update 2, it was no issue, but something has changed to git integration with VS after this update and now it's being included. Whenever my workmates pull changes to the branch, their IIS Express fails because of the changes to this file (it has paths local to my own PC's paths etc.) and vice versa.

How do I pull this file out of the source control completely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 19):

Do you have `applicationhost.config` file already in repository before adding it to `.gitignore` file?

If so you need to use command `git rm --cached [file]`.

Purpose of `.gitignore` file is to keep untracked files untracked, so it wont affect files that you already track.

**EDIT:**

As I totally forgot:
Above solution works for repository, so all developers working will be forced to maintain their own copy.

To prevent git from detecting changes you should also use this:
`git update-index --assume-unchanged [path_or_file]`
And if - in future - you would want to start tracking changes again you'll need to revert update via:
`git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>`

And to see files marked with `--assume-uchanged` flag you can use this:
`git ls-files -v | grep '^[[:lower:]]'`
See documentation for [git ls-files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files).

I believe [this](http://source.kohlerville.com/2009/02/untrack-files-in-git/) blog entry can be more descriptive.

Comment: Did this, it removed the file from git. Then I've pushed, my friend pulled and the problem still continues.

Comment: There are two options now: you'r friend can maintain his/her own local copy by using the same instruction, or you could update index via: `git update-index --assume-unchanged`. I'll update answer in a second.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I'm not sure how notify'ing on SO works, so just in case: I updated answer. Hope it'll help!

Answer (score 7):

Try the command:

```
git rm /.vs/config/applicationhost.config
```

Then commit changes to repository.

The line in .gitignore just give to git information, that this file should not be listed as "untracked files" in git status output

Comment: Why did this get down voted? The file is generated by VS, deleting the file doesn't seem to make any issues for VS. 

Adding it to .gitignore and deleting it from the repository seems fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did a little more looking around and found this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313126/how-to-remove-a-directory-in-my-github-repository
Which has better answers.